# Fazer Loading Screen animada - Unity 5.1

Tags: c#, unity3d, jogos

Estou tendo problemas para fazer uma Loading Screen pro meu game, o game está um pouco grande então demora um certo tempo para carregar, ainda mais por ser um game mobile. No momento estou tentando fazer assim:

```cs
public bool loading = false;
public Texture loadingTexture;
public float size = 70.0;
private float rotAngle = 0.0;
public float rotSpeed = 300.0;

void Update () {
    if(loading){
        rotAngle += rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }   
}

void OnGUI() {

    if(loading){

        Vector2 pivot = new Vector2(Screen.width/2, Screen.height/2);
        GUIUtility.RotateAroundPivot(rotAngle%360,pivot);

        GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect ((Screen.width - size)/2 , (Screen.height - size)/2, size, size), loadingTexture); 

    }
}
```

```cs
//Código onde carrega a Scene

public void StartGame()
{
  Application.LoadLevel("Game");
  GameObject.find("Loading").GetComponent<LoadingScreen>().loading = true;
}
```

Porém toda vez que peço pro jogo iniciar, ele aparece a tela de loading mas não executa a animação, ele fica totalmente travado até o jogo iniciar. Não sei mais o que fazer. Me ajudem, por favor!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Criar uma "scene" só para a screen de loading que não seja muito pesada (senão tens de fazer um loading para o loading XD)

Cria um objecto e coloca este script dentro da função update na scene "loading"

```
if(Application.GetStreamProgressForLevel("nomedolevel") ==1){
        Application.LoadLevel("nomedolevel");
    }
```

Tem só atenção que a scene loading tem de estar acima da scene a ser carregada. Ex

loading
level1
loading
level2

Também podes usar

[LoadLevelAsync](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.LoadLevelAsync.html)